# different results with icontains in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm filtering results from django database (mysql) with the following:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(value_name__icontains=search).order_by("pk")


class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    value_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "my_table"
```

The collation value for field `value_name=utf8mb4_0900_bin`

When the value of `search = "bin"` I'm getting one set of results,
Results are having substring "bin" in them.

and when the value of `search="Bin"` i'm getting another set of results.
Results are having substring "Bin" in them.

The results of both of these don't have any intersection.

It looks like a collation issue, how to fix this?
I can't change anything on the database, as I only have read access.

My django version is 3.2.

I tried this but it did not work.

`value_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, db_collation='utf8_general_ci')`

Comment: SOmething is missing from this code - is `value` a FK? You're picking `value_type` and `value_name` from that relation, not `MyModel.value_name`. Also, are you on SQLite? Edit: sorry - I see MySQL ... missed that!

Comment: @michjnich I've simplified the queryset and removek the FK, as they won't matter in this case.

Comment: I think it's your collation anyway - see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is the collation.

Your table has `managed=False`, so changing the field definition on the model to set the collation won't help you. You need to check the table definition in the actual database - if the collation is not defined there, it won't work.

Comment: I've update the question with this: The collation value for field value_name=utf8mb4_0900_bin

Comment: My point was that it makes no difference if you change collation value on the model definition ,because the table has `managed=False` - you need to set it in the DB to whatever it needs to be.